Is the appearance of a substance a substance?
I read the below from here, but I don't follow it:

We cannot apply the concepts substance/accident to any object but
appearances, objects in space and/or time. For example, we might
try to apply it to ourselves as thinking beings. "In all our thought
the 'I' is the subject, in which thoughts inhere only as
determinations; and this 'I' cannot be employed as determination of
another thing. Everyone must, therefore, necessarily regard himself as
substance, and thought as only accidents of his being, determinations
of his state" (A349). This application of the category of substance is
empty, however, unless it states something about the persistence of
substance over time. Hence, it is of value only when applied to
appearances. The mere representation of ourselves as thinking does not
yield any information about our temporal properties. (This is argued
in the First Paralogism.)
The application of the category of substance to appearances takes
place only insofar as the category has a "schema" connecting it with
time. The schema of substance is permanence, i.e., persistence through
time. Correspondingly, accidents are the transitory. So to bring
appearances under the concept of substance, we think them as
consisting of persisting beings which transitory states. That we are
justified in so thinking them, and indeed must think appearances this
way, is argued in the First Analogy.

I cannot determine from this passage if 'I' is a substance or not.  The passage seems to be taking both sides of the fence.  If the appearance is transitory, how can it be categorized as substance?

"'I' cannot be employed as determination of another thing. Everyone must, therefore, necessarily regard himself as substance" seems plain enough. The quote goes on to explain what this "regarding" entails. Appearances taken as substances must conform with the schema connecting substance to time, and so `I' has to be conceived as persistent through time with its thoughts as transitory accidents. More generally, we "must think appearances" as "persisting beings which transitory states".

"Yet man's 'substance' is not spirit as a synthesis of soul and body; it is rather existence." (B&T, H. 117)

Appearance vs substance, as used here, sounds to me very much like the epistemic vs ontological interpretations of the quantum-mechanical wavefunction, e.g., https://bigthink.com/13-8/qbism-philosophical-crisis-quantum-mechanics/ or google epistemic vs ontological quantum interpretation (or anything similar) for about a zillion other references. There are tons of discussions/arguments/etc about this stuff. Briefly, ontological means the wavefunction describes actual properties of real physical systems(objects). Epistemic means it only describes our human knowledge about such systems(objects)
